# Failing to create a directory in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, directory

I don't have that much experience on python but I've tried a few things and nothing worked yet on this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: ./logsSat Jun  9
>   20:44:37 2018-training; Invalid argument

It's happening on what should be a simple part of the code, which is to create a file to store the data from an sklearn dataset on. Here is a part of the code:

```
epochs = 500
logpath = './logs'
resultpath = './results'

def main(epochs, logpath, resultpath):

    # load the features of the dataset
    features = datasets.load_breast_cancer().data

    # standardize the features
    features = StandardScaler().fit_transform(features)

    # get the number of features
    num_features = features.shape[1]

    # load the labels for the features
    labels = datasets.load_breast_cancer().target

    train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.20,
                                                                                stratify=labels)

    model = MLP.MLP(alpha=LEARNING_RATE, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, node_size=NUM_NODES, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES,
                    num_features=num_features)

    model.train(num_epochs=epochs, log_path=logpath, train_data=[train_features, train_labels],
                train_size=train_features.shape[0], test_data=[test_features, test_labels],
                test_size=test_features.shape[0], result_path=resultpath)
```

Apparently './logs' is not how I should input that directory name, so any ideas to make this work? I've tried using only the directory name, the full path and using sys.path.append("..") syntax but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Does the path `./logs` exist yet?  If not, make it and try again.

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end of ./logs -- so `./logs/`?

Comment: I tried without a logs folder and after creating it, still get the error.

Comment: Tried adding the / but got the same error: "InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: ./logs/Sat Jun  9 23:28:13 2018-training; Invalid argument"

Comment: It looks like it's treating the entire string `./logsSat Jun 9 20:44:37 2018-training` as the directory to be created.

Comment: yeah, the {Sat Jun 9 20:44:37 2018-training} part is the generated file name, but for some reason, even adding the / between the directory and file still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be another `/`at the end of `./logs`because it is interpreting the whole thing as a single statement.

Comment: Tried adding the / but got the same error: "InvalidArgumentError: Failed to create a directory: ./logs/Sat Jun 9 23:28:13 2018-training; Invalid argument"

Comment: Actually I noticed something weird now, I've deleted the logs folder I created before and noticed the program is now creating the logs folder correctly. But I still get the same error message as I pasted above and the program won't run because of it, so the created folder is empty.